# CUDA: cudaEvent_t and cudaThreadSynchronize usage

Tags: timer, cuda

I am a bit confused about the usage of `cudaEvent_t`. Currently, I am using the `clock()` call like this to find the duration of a kernel call:

```
cudaThreadSynchronize();
clock_t begin = clock();

fooKernel<<< x, y >>>( z, w );

cudaThreadSynchronize();
clock_t end = clock();

// Print time difference: ( end - begin )
```

Looking for a timer of higher-resolution I am considering using `cudaEvent_t`. Do I need to call `cudaThreadSynchronize()` before I note down the time using `cudaEventRecord()` or is it redundant?

The reason I am asking is because there is another call `cudaEventSynchronize()`, which seems to wait until the event is recorded. If the recording is delayed, won't the time difference that is calculated show some extra time after the kernel has finished execution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually there are even more synchronization functions (`cudaStreamSynchronize`). The programming guide has a detailed description what every one of those does. Using events as timers basically comes down to this:

```
//create events
cudaEvent_t event1, event2;
cudaEventCreate(&event1);
cudaEventCreate(&event2);

//record events around kernel launch
cudaEventRecord(event1, 0); //where 0 is the default stream
kernel<<<grid,block>>>(...); //also using the default stream
cudaEventRecord(event2, 0);

//synchronize
cudaEventSynchronize(event1); //optional
cudaEventSynchronize(event2); //wait for the event to be executed!

//calculate time
float dt_ms;
cudaEventElapsedTime(&dt_ms, event1, event2);
```

It's important to synchronize on `event2` because you want to make sure everything got executed before calculating the time. As both events and the kernel are on the same stream (order is preserved) `event1` and `kernel` got executed too.

You could call `cudaStreamSynchronize` or even `cudaThreadSynchronize` instead but both are overkill in this case.

Comment: LumpN: Why isn't the event recorded as soon cudaEventRecord is called? If it is not recorded on that call, how is it representing the time taken by that kernel?

Comment: @Ashwin: The event is recorded when it reaches to top of stream, which is acting like a FIFO. When you call cudaEventRecord, you are pushing an event into the stream. If there is work in the stream ahead of the event, the event sits unprocessed in the stream FIFO until every operation ahead of it has completed. All these calls are asynchronous with respect to the calling host thread.